# How to implement the Roll angle together with Yaw and Pitch in glm::lookAt function?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, camera-roll, glulookat

From this page https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera I learned how to implement the Yaw and Pitch angle to a glm::lookAt function. But sadly I could not find any reference of how to add also the Roll angle to the funcion.

When I try to implement it, the x and z axis keep constant, and don't adapt to the Roll rotation.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: The "roll" angle is defined by the up vector.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you really need to use roll for camera movement, as it's uncommon unless you are making a camera that follows something that flies. You change roll by rotating the up vector about the front vector (which will be unchanged), so it should look something like

```
up.y = up.y * cos(rollAngle)
up.x = ...
up.z = ...
```

where x and z will have 2 terms, depending on x and z of the front vector, similar to how the tutorial calculated the front vector depended on yaw and pitch
You might want to consider a linear algebra library like Eigen as it will take care of rotations and other things you will probably need pretty easily using their Transform api.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to calculate x and z?